# SpriteKit draw upside down text

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

In a playground, I am trying to make a SpriteKit scene with a top left origin going down (ie like a drawing program). Everything works except for text which is flipped. I need to make the text right side up. I am missing something. If I add the translate and scale, the text vanishes.

```
//: A SpriteKit based Playground

import PlaygroundSupport
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene
{
    static let width = 1000
    static let height = 1800
    override func didMove(to view: SKView)
    {
        self.backgroundColor = SKColor.white

        let cam = SKCameraNode()

        self.camera = cam
        cam.yScale = -1

        let node = SKSpriteNode(color: SKColor.yellow, size: CGSize(width: 500, height: 300))
        node.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
        node.position = CGPoint(x: 10, y: 10)

        let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: CGSize(width: 200, height: 200))
        let img = renderer.image { ctx in
            let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
            paragraphStyle.alignment = .center

            let attrs = [NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont(name: "Futura", size: 72)!, NSAttributedStringKey.paragraphStyle: paragraphStyle]

            //ctx.cgContext.translateBy(x: 0, y:200)
            //ctx.cgContext.scaleBy(x: 0, y: -1)
            let string = "Test"
            string.draw(with: CGRect(x: 32, y: 32, width: 200, height: 200), options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin, attributes: attrs, context: nil)
        }

        let tex = SKTexture(image: img)
        let zzz = SKSpriteNode(texture: tex)
        zzz.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
        zzz.position = CGPoint(x: 10, y: 10)

        node.addChild(zzz)

//        let z = SKSpriteNode(color: SKColor.red, size: CGSize(width: 200, height: 150))
//        z.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
//        z.position = CGPoint(x: 10, y: 10)
//        node.addChild(z)
//
//        let q = SKSpriteNode(color: SKColor.green, size: CGSize(width: 80, height: 70))
//        q.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
//        q.position = CGPoint(x: 10, y: 10)
//        z.addChild(q)

        self.addChild(node)
        self.addChild(cam)
        cam.position = CGPoint(x: GameScene.width/2, y: GameScene.height/2)
    }
}

let sceneView = SKView(frame: CGRect(x:0 , y:0, width: 480, height: 640))
let scene = GameScene(size: CGSize(width: GameScene.width, height: GameScene.height))
scene.scaleMode = .aspectFit
sceneView.presentScene(scene)
PlaygroundSupport.PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = sceneView
```

Update:

```
        ctx.cgContext.textMatrix = .identity
        ctx.cgContext.translateBy(x: 0, y: 200)
        ctx.cgContext.scaleBy(x: 1.0, y: -1.0)
```

now draws the text rightside up, but it is wrapped at 50% of the width

Final Update:

This worked, its rightsize up. The font size is proportional to the scene size (which is a dimension that fits on all iOS devices.

```
self.camera = cam
cam.yScale = -1

let boxSize = CGSize(width: 500, height: 500)

let node = SKSpriteNode(color: SKColor.yellow, size: boxSize)
node.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
node.position = CGPoint(x: 10, y: 10)

let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: boxSize)
let img = renderer.image { ctx in

    let bounds = CGRect(x: 16, y: 0, width: boxSize.width-32, height: boxSize.height)
    let string = "This is a long test with many lines."
    let range = NSRange( location: 0, length: string.count)
    guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return }
    let path = CGMutablePath()
    path.addRect(bounds)
    let attrString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: string)
    attrString.addAttribute(NSAttributedStringKey.font, value: UIFont(name: "Futura", size: 84)!, range: range )
    let framesetter = CTFramesetterCreateWithAttributedString(attrString as CFAttributedString)
    let frame = CTFramesetterCreateFrame(framesetter, CFRangeMake(0, attrString.length), path, nil)
    CTFrameDraw(frame, context)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should read https://www.raywenderlich.com/153591/core-text-tutorial-ios-making-magazine-app

CoreText inverts (technically, rotates) text in iOS. This is possibly because it is shared with MacOS which uses a different coordinate system. (Though why they couldn't fix this for iOS I have no idea).

Whatever the cause, you aren't doing anything wrong, iOS is doing the wrong thing. The simple solution (as per the linked article) is to simply rotate the text before drawing it.

Comment: I will try the suggestion next.